# C++ when are typedefs in standard library containers not what you would expect?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

For which standard library container types are the typedefs within the container not what you would naively think?

In code, under which conditions on the type `T` and the container `container_type` do the following static checks not all evaluate to true:

```
typedef double T;
typedef std::vector<T> container_type;

std::is_same<typename container_type::value_type, T>::value; 
std::is_same<typename container_type::reference, T&>::value; 
std::is_same<typename container_type::const_reference, T const&>::value; 
std::is_same<typename container_type::pointer, T*>::value;  
std::is_same<typename container_type::const_pointer, T const*>::value;
```

I only know of `std::vector<bool>::reference` which is not `bool&` (and probably this is the same for the `const` version thereof).

Are there others?

Comment: For `map` and `unordered_map`, there is no `T`. `value_type` is `pair<const key_type,mapped_type>`.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: sure, but I think you got the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any container containing objects of type `T`, the standard (C++11 23.2.1/4) requires that:

- `container_type::value_type` is `T`
- `container_type::reference` is an lvalue of `T`, i.e. a `T&`
- `container_type::const_reference` is a const lvalue of `T`, i.e. a `const T&`

`pointer` and `const_pointer` are not part of any of the `Container` requirements, they are simply convenience typedefs in the standard containers, taken from the container's allocator.

So, to answer your question:

`value_type`, `reference` and `const_reference` must be as you expect, otherwise the container does not satisfy `Container` requirements. Notice that this means (as e.g. [Herb Sutter points out](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm)), that `std::vector<bool>` is *not* a container in the standard sense.

`pointer` and `const_pointer` are typedefs to the allocator types, so when you have a container with allocator `A`, they will differ from `T*` and `T const*` whenever `std::allocator_traits<A>::pointer` and `std::allocator_traits<A>::const_pointer` differ from them.

And to directly address the question of which standard containers satisfy these `Container` requirements:

- `std::array<T>` does, per 23.3.2.1/3 (with some exceptions which don't affect the typedefs in question)
- `std::deque<T>` does, per 23.3.3.1/2
- `std::forward_list<T>` does, per 23.3.4.1/2 (with some exceptions which don't affect the typedefs in question)
- `std::list<T>` does, per 23.3.5.1/2
- `std::vector<T>` does (for `T` other than `bool`), per 23.3.6.1/2 (with some exceptions which don't affect the typedefs in question)
- `std::set<T>` does, per 23.4.6.1/2
- `std::multiset<T>` does, per 23.4.7.1/2
- `std::unrdered_set<T>` does, per 23.5.6.1/2
- `std::unordered_multiset<T>` does, per 23.5.7.1/2
- `std::basic_string<T>` contains the typedefs in question (to the correct types) as per 21.4./5, even though the standard does not explicitly require it to satisfy the `Container` requirements. Note that `value_type` depends on the character traits, so `std::basic_string<T, MyTraits>` can have `value_type` other than `T`.

`std::[unorderd_][multi]map` don't qualify because they take more than one mandatory template parameter and use them to synthesise `value_type`.

`std::valarray<T>` does not qualify because it only provides the `value_type` typedef and none of the others.

Comment: thanks, nice answer, but it immediately raises a related question: for which combinations of `container_type` and `T` is `container_type<T>` not a `Container`? Only for `std::vector<bool>`?

Comment: @davidhigh and when would it be legal for users to specialize a std container to do, well, whatever? ;)

Comment: @Yak: sorry, I should have said that, I refered to POD types for `T`.

Comment: @davidhigh You mean fundamental types, right? A user-defined type can still be POD.

Comment: A user can provide specializations for any of the standard templates, provided the specialization depends on a user defined type.  The specialization must meet the requirements for the original template, however.

Comment: the question in my first comment remains: for which fundamental types and which containers is `container_type<T>` (--provided it exists) a `Container` in the sense of the standard?

Comment: For any container of type `T`? Do you mean: For any container of type `container_type`?

Comment: @MWid Clarified; I meant it in the sense of "`vector<int>` is a container of `int`s."

Comment: Do you say that for `template<typename T> class MyContainer;` it must hold `MyContainer<T>::value_type == T` to satisfy the container requirements?

Comment: IMHO it's a defect that `pointer` is not part of the container requirements, we're missing wording that says containers should use `pointer` internall instead of `value_type*`, see http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2261

Comment: As for `valarray`, there's a reason it's in a totally separate clause. It's not a container, never has been, never will be. Any similarity with real containers, living or dead, is purely coincidental.

Comment: @JonathanWakely `valarray`: I agree. But I think it warrants a mention in a list such as this one.

Comment: @MWid No, I hope that's not implied anywhere in the answer, as that is not what I meant. Still, it does hold for all `std` containers (except for key-value pair ones).